# ImportError: Ipython requires Python version 2.7 or 3.3 or above

Tags: python, paths, ipython

I am trying to use ipython notebook. But when i execute ipython notebook, it gives me below error. 
I have both ipython 2.7, and 3.3. 
But even than it can not detect ipython 2.7. 
How can i append the path without deleting previous paths.

```
ihn@cri8:/home/ihn/packages$ ipython notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>
from IPython import start_ipython
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
raise ImportError('IPython requires Python version 2.7 or 3.3 or above.')
ImportError: IPython requires Python version 2.7 or 3.3 or above.
```

if i type

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ python -V
Python 2.7.3
```

I can use EXPORT = path $path. But in that case it will delete my previous paths in bashrc file. How can i append this path in it?

Answer (score 0):

### Ubuntu 20.04 and later

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install jupyter-notebook jupyter
```

### Ubuntu 18.04 and later

```
sudo apt install python3-notebook jupyter jupyter-core python-ipykernel
```

To start the notebook server run the following command:

```
jupyter notebook
```

You should see Jupyter Notebook open in your web browser.

---

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install ipython3 ipython3-notebook
```

To start Interactive Python 3 html notebook type:

```
ipython3 notebook
```

To start Python notebook with inline Python based plotting system (*python-matplotlib*):

```
ipython notebook --pylab
```

or for Python 3 and python3-matplotlib:

```
ipython3 notebook --pylab
```